# How can I transform latitude and longitude to x,y in Java?

Tags: algorithm, math, transform, geography

I am working on a geographic project in Java.

The input are coordinates : 24.4444 N etc 
Output: a PLAIN map (not round) showing the point of the coordinates.

I don't know the algorithm to transform from coordinates to x,y on a JComponent, can somebody help me?

The map looks like this: 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Mercator-projection.jpg

Thank you

Comment: How large of a region do you want the `JComponent` to show? And are all your coordinates at low latitudes? (near the equator) Or do you have some near/at the poles?

Comment: Are you asking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection?  The commonly-used projection from spherical to flat?  Or do you need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyconic_projection?  Is this what you're asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your sparse example, the range of your inputs will be (90.0N - 90.0S) and (180W - 180E). It is easiest - and standard - if you convert South and West to negatives giving you latitudes of (90.0..-90.0) and longitudes of (180.0..-180.0).

Given the size of your canvas - let's say it is 140x120 pixels - you get:

```
x = (latitude * canvas_height / 180.0) + (canvas_height / 2)
y = (longitude * canvas_width / 360.0) + (canvas_width / 2)
```

or:

```
x = (longitude * 120.0 / 180.0) + (120/2)
y = (latitude  * 140.0 / 360.0) + (140/2)
```

where I have ordered the operations to minimize rounding error. This assumes the canvas has point (0,0) in the upper-left or, if not, that you are Australian.

**Added**: you just threw in the bit about Mercator projections making my simple answer incorrect (but possibly still usable by you if you don't actually care about projection)

Comment: Yes, there is a domain overlap at the anti-meridian, but I don't think the OP will be plotting many points in suburban Tavuki, Fiji, and even Google Earth gets a little wonky there.

Comment: This isn't a mercator projection, which is what his map uses.

Comment: I don't exactly need the Mercator. Can you suggest me a flat map which I can use for you algorithm ?

Comment: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World-162E-flat.svg Please note that flat projections like this are hardly ever used and so look funny. Also note that it is centered - like it says - on 162E which would have to be taken into account in the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

MSW provided a good example.  Ultimately the algorithm depends on the map projection used.  Here are a couple of good resources I used in the past.

The following link is a good reference to a number of different map projections with enough math formulas to choke a horse.

http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/

Here is a decent reference for doing this in PhP.  While not Java, it should be straight forward enough to apply the principles outlined.

http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/article_1.php